# Define static anonymous enum outside the class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums, static-members

So I have class like this:

```
class Foo
{
static enum {a,b,c} member;
}
```

A fine one member class. But, there is a need for defining static members outside classes. Using my VS 2013 I tried:

```
enum {a,b,c} Foo::member;
```

But it failed. Is there any way of defining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decltype`:

```
class Foo
{
    static enum {a,b,c} member;
};  // <--- also note semicolon

decltype(Foo::member) Foo::member;
```